# Mongoose handle duplicate url slug

Tags: string, mongoose, slug

I am storing url slugs from blog titles in MongoDB using Mongoose. So for instances when users enter the same blog title, I want to do it like how Wordpress handles it which is appending a number on the slug and increment it for every duplicates.

Example:

1. blog-title
2. blog-title-2
3. blog-title-3

Also when the slug evaluated from a blog title is blog-title-2 and there is already a blog-title-2 slug, it will be smart enough to append -2 at the back instead of incrementing the number. So it will be blog-title-2-2.

How do I implement that?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure out how to implement it myself.

```
function setSlug(req, res, next) {
  // remove special chars, trim spaces, replace all spaces to dashes, lowercase everything
  var slug = req.body.title.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '').trim().replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
  var counter = 2;
  // check if there is existing blog with same slug
  Blog.findOne({ slug: slug }, checkSlug);
  // recursive function for checking repetitively
  function checkSlug(err, existingBlog) {
    if(existingBlog) { // if there is blog with the same slug
      if(counter == 2) // if first round, append '-2'
        slug = slug.concat('-' + counter++);
      else // increment counter on slug (eg: '-2' becomes '-3')
        slug = slug.replace(new RegExp(counter++ + '$', 'g'), counter);
      Blog.findOne({ slug: slug }, checkSlug); // check again with the new slug
    } else { // else the slug is set
      req.body.slug = slug;
      next();
    }
  };
}
```

I played around with Wordpress for a bit; publishing a lot of test blog posts with weird titles just to see how it handles the title conversion and I implemented the first step in converting the title according to my discoveries. Wordpress:

- removes all special characters
- trims away leading and ending spaces
- converts remaining spaces to single dashes
- lowercase everything

Answer (score 0):

In your mongooese model you can give the field the unique option:

```
var post = new post({
  slug: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
  }
});
```

Then when you save it you can validate and know if the slug is not unique, in which case you can modify the slug:

```
var post = new post({ slug: "i-am-slug"});
var tempSlug = post.slug
var slugIsUnique = true;
car counter = 1;
do{
  error = post.validateSync();
  if(// not unique ){ //Make sure to only check for errors on post.slug here
    slugIsUnique = false;
    counter++;
    tempSlug = post.slug + "-" + counter;
  }
}while(!slugIsUnique)

post.slug = tempSlug;
post.save((err, post) => {
  // check for error or do the usual thing
});
```

**Edit:**
This wont take blog-title-2 and output blog-title-2-2 but it will ouput blog-title-2-1 unless that already exists

Answer (score 0):

I found the following code worked for me:

The general idea is to create an array of slugs you may potentially want to use and then use the MongoDB's [$in query operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) to determine if any of those slugs exist.

Note: The below solutions uses [NPM's slugify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/slugify). This is optional. I also use crytpo for randomizing since it has higher performance.  Which is also optional.

```
private getUniqueSlug(title: string) {
    // Returns a promise to allow async code.
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        const uniqueSlug: string = "";
        // uses npm slugify. You can use whichever library you want or make your own.
        const slug: string = slugify(title, { lower: true, strict: true });

        // determines if slug is an ObjectID
        const slugIsObjId: boolean = (ObjectId.isValid(slug) && !!slug.match(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/));

        // creates a list of slugs (add/remove to your preference)
        const slugs: string[] = [];
        // ensures slug is not an ObjectID
        slugIsObjId ? slugs.push(slug + "(1)") : slugs.push(slug);
        slugs.push(slug + "(2)");
        slugs.push(slug + "(3)");
        slugs.push(slug + "(4)");
        slugs.push(slug + "(5)");

        // Optional. 3 random as fallback (crypto used to generate a random 4 character string)
        for (let x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
            slugs.push(slug + "(" + crypto.randomBytes(2).toString("hex") + ")");
        }

        // Uses a single find instance for performance purposes
        // $in searches for all collections with a slug in slugs array above
        const query: any = { slug: { $in: slugs } };
        Collection.find(query, { slug: true }).then((results) => {
            if (results) {
                results.forEach((result) => {
                    slugs.every((s, si) => {
                        // If match found, remove from slugs since that slug ID is not valid.
                        if (s === result.slug) { slugs.splice(si, 1); return false; } else { return true; }
                    });
                });
            }
            // returns first slug. Slugs are ordered by priority
            if (slugs.length > 0) { resolve(slugs[0]); } else {
                reject("Unable to generate a unique slug."); // Note: If no slug, then fails. Can use ObjectID as failsafe (nearly impossible).
            }
        }, (err) => {
            reject("Find failed");
        });
    });
}
```